# (iOS/Swift) Simple GET Request with Path Variables Params

Tags: ios, swift, postman, alamofire, get-request

I am testing a `GET request` using `Postman`. In Params tab, there is `Path Variable` with an "id" `key` and a `value`. You can see the `URL` of `GET request` in this screenshot below, there is `url path`  **/:id**  in the end of the `URL` endpoint.

[image]

How to perform `GET request` with Path Variables params as such in Swift?

Thanks

Comment: in postman, you can see "Code" options that will show code in swift also, check that maybe help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Params tab, there is 'Path Variable' with an "id" key and a value**

This means you can replace this `:/id` with your actual id value in url.

```
func getRequestAPICall()  {

        let apiUrl : String = "your_server_url" + "/" + "yourIdValueHere"

        Alamofire.request(apiUrl, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
            }
    }
```

Comment: Oh man, my bad! Thanks for the answer! This is my first time using Postman. The answer is so simple :(

Answer (score -1):

Simple Request using `URLSession`

```
func getAPDemo(url:URL){

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in


             // handle data , error here according to need
        }
        task.resume()

  }
```

Comment: why it is downvoting ? please comment to elaborate issue with solution provided.

Comment: You did not provide code to add path arguments as requested.